# TypeError: can't concat list to bytes Python Telnet Error

Tags: python, telnetlib

I have an function that i want to call over CMD in Windows.
Problem here is that the function "telnetlib(write)" wants "Bytes".
Now if i do the sys.argv i get the error "TypeError: can't concat list to bytes"

My Code:

```
import telnetlib
import time
import sys


def roland(param):
    host = "172.xxxx"
    port = 23
    timeout = 100
    pb = b'PA:A1,'
    play = pb+param

    with telnetlib.Telnet(host, port, timeout) as session:
        print("Sending Password...")
        time.sleep(1)
        session.write(b"XXX\r\n")
        print("Password out!")

        time.sleep(1)
        print("sending to:1")
        session.write(b"to:1\r\n")
        print("Sended to:1")

        time.sleep(1)
        print("sending Music")
        print(play)
        session.write(play + b'\r\n')
        print("Sended Music")

        time.sleep(1)
        print("sending PL")
        session.write(b"PL\r\n")
        print("sended PL")

        time.sleep(1)
        print("sending logout")
        session.write(b"logout\r\n")
        print("sended logout")
        session.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
     roland(sys.argv)
```

Added:
param = param.encode('ascii')

Changed:
roland(sys.argv) to roland(sys.argv[1])

Comment: You are getting ther error because you `can't concat list to bytes`. Hint: `argv` is a list.

Comment: argv[1] but you'll probably need to check the value of arg[1]

Comment: tried with sys.argv[1] now. 
Now i gett cant concat str to bytes.
Somehow i cant convert the "param" to bytes with param.encode('ascii')

Comment: nvm. "param = param.encode('ascii')" worked.Big Thanks!